# how to get the previous checked position in list view

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Actually I had a list view when I touch on the list view I will get popup window with check boxes when I check the check box and press OK then the dialog box closes and when I touch again the list view then the checked row position will change the background color and and stored into the data base. actually what was the issue is when I again select different item position and checked and press OK and again touch the list view instead of entering the checked position entering into data base the previously checked position also entering into data base along with current checked position. so I need to get previous position and clear position before the list view sees the checked positions. so that it only enters current position.

**My activity**

```
listView1.setOnTouchListener(new AdapterView.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            newListitems2.clear();
            newListitems2.addAll(itemsList1);

            dialog = new Dialog(PendingOrdersActitvity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.itembumping);

            dialog.show();

            //listView1.setTag(position);
            list1 = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.list1);

            ItemBumpingAdapter adapter2 = new ItemBumpingAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, newListitems2);
            list1.setAdapter(adapter2);

            Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok1);
            okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Cancel1);
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Implimented code :

```
listView1.setOnTouchListener(new AdapterView.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){



                     newListitems2.clear();
                  newListitems2.addAll(itemsList1);

                     dialog = new Dialog(PendingOrdersActitvity.this);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.itembumping);

                        dialog.show();





                        list1=(ListView )dialog.findViewById(R.id.list1);


                        ItemBumpingAdapter adapter2 = new ItemBumpingAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this,newListitems2);
                        list1.setAdapter(adapter2);






                        Button okButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok1);
                        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                dialog.dismiss();


                                Connection con1 = DbHandler.dbConnection();
                                try{
                                PreparedStatement stmt1 = con1
                                        .prepareStatement("Select Line_No, ItemName,DeleteFlag from PendingOrders_Dtl where Inv_No=? ");

                                stmt1.setString(1,invNo);
                                ResultSet rsSetup1 = stmt1.executeQuery();


                                if (rsSetup1.next()) {
                                    ItemsBean bean1 = new ItemsBean();


                                        bean1.setLinenum(rsSetup1.getInt("Line_No"));
                                        bean1.setProdnum(rsSetup1.getInt("ItemName"));

                                        bean1.setDeleteFlag(rsSetup1.getInt("DeleteFlag"));
                                    disablelist.add(bean1);



                                }

                                CustomAdapter adapter1 = new CustomAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, itemsList1);
                                    for(int i=0;i<itemsList1.size();i++)
                                    {
                                        for(int j=0;j<disablelist.size();j++)
                                        {
                                        if(itemsList1.get(i).getProdnum()==disablelist.get(j).getProdnum())
                                        {

                                            itemsList1.get(i).setSelection(true);



                                        }




                            }
                            }
                                }
                                catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                 });
```

Comment: Try add "list1.clearChoices();" before create adapter2. Hope that help!

Comment: i will try thank you

Comment: Sorry! mis-understanded your question. You are checked CheckBox, not ListItem. Therefore try add this: "for(int i=0; i<newListitems2.size(); i++){ ListItem tmpItem = newListitems2.get(i); tmpItem.setChecked(false); newListitems2.remove(i); newListitems2.add(i, tmpItem);}" before create adapter2. Hope this help!

Comment: can u plzz impliment this in code

Comment: means please edit it in my code

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  int previousPosition;

     public int getPreviousPosition() {
return previousPosition;
 }


 public void setPreviousPosition(int previousPosition) {
this.previousPosition = previousPosition;
 }
```

and in your listview on item selected listener

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         int prePos=  getPreviousPosition();
      // do what ever you want to do with this prePos      



     View viewchild= parent.getChildAt(getPreviousPosition());
            CheckBox prevCheckBox=(CheckBox)viewchild.findViewById(R.id.Checkbox_sort_list);
            prevCheckBox.setChecked(false);

      //at ending of list view write this
            setPreviousPosition(position);

        }
    });
```

Comment: but how can i clear before position and stop entering into data base

Comment: i didnt understand your question completely, if you want the previous checbox to get unchecked ,i have edited the code to do that

Answer (score 0):

I think you have kept the checked positions in itemList1, so after you copy it to newListitems2, you need to clear the checked positions in newListitems2.
Try this:

```
listView1.setOnTouchListener(new AdapterView.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        newListitems2.clear();
        newListitems2.addAll(itemsList1);

        dialog = new Dialog(PendingOrdersActitvity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.itembumping);

        dialog.show();

        //listView1.setTag(position);
        list1 = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.list1);

        // Uncheck all items of newListitems2
        for(int i=0; i<newListitems2.size(); i++){
            ItemsBean tmpItem = newListitems2.get(i);
            tmpItem.setChecked(false);
            newListitems2.remove(i);
            newListitems2.add(i, tmpItem);
        }

        ItemBumpingAdapter adapter2 = new ItemBumpingAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, newListitems2);
        list1.setAdapter(adapter2);

        Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok1);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Cancel1);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
}
});
```

For the other issue:

Method 1:

If the list in the popup dialog is the same as main list, then may be try: when dialog is dismissed, get the list from popup dialog and copy it to main list.

1. Add method in Adapter class to get the list from adapter2:

   ```
   public ArrayList<ItemsBean> getItemList(){
      return newListitems;
   }
   ```
2. When okbutton clicked, over-write the main list and dismiss the dialog:

   ```
   itemsList1 = adapter2.getItemList();
   adapter1 = new ItemBumpingAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, itemList1);
   adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
   dialog.dismiss();
   ```

Method 2:

1. Add method to adapter1 to check items:

   ```
   public void checkItemsAccordingDatabase(){
       for(int i=0; i<newListItems; i++){
           ItemsBean tmpItem = newListItems.get(i);
           // query tmpItem in database.
           // if tmpItem exits, newListItems.get(i).setChecked(true).
       }
       notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```
2. When okbutton clicked, update the main list and dismiss the dialog:

   ```
   adapter1.checkItemsAccordingDatabase();
   dialog.dismiss();
   ```

Comment: ListItem tmpItem = newListitems2.get(i);

Comment: What is your item in the list? In your post code, I don't found it, so I just make it ListItem.

Comment: ok, thank you but i have another issue would u like to help me

Comment: Please check if this works first. Does the other issue relate to the post?

Comment: i cant give item name because it is am using bean type arraylist . so in adapter i implimented code as when i checked then enters into database instead of entering after loading list view . so now i have another issue related to same project

Comment: i will check it

Comment: tnq ,but its not getting .I have solved proble now , i have another issue

Comment: i would like to thank u for ur  quick response in solving my issue

Comment: Please comment if I understand your another issue correctly.

Comment: actually i have list view now when i click on the list view am getting popup window of same list items with check box. when i check the check box of any item in popup window i have to disable the same item what i checked have to change background color of same item in main list .am using two adapters for main list and other for popup list. now when i check the item in popup list it is entering into database . now i have to take that item and set flag  and change color of same item in main list. i don't know how to set flag by selecting it  from database

Comment: by that way we can modify the background color in main list

Comment: can i chat with u regarding my project?if so i would be thankful to u\

Comment: Actually what the issue is items are getting from database so it cant be possible to copy from one adapter

Comment: main list SAME AS popup list. I still cant get the point why cant copy popup list back to main list. By the way, I draft Method 2 that use database but the query command looks complex and leave it for you. In addition, in the posted adapter, you add items to database in getView()?? I think that should be in a seperate method and called when dialog dismiss.

Comment: is there other way to contact to u bcz here we cant keep more comments

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Move this after setSelection.
// CustomAdapter adapter1 = new CustomAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, itemsList1);

for(int i=0;i<itemsList1.size();i++){
    for(int j=0;j<disablelist.size();j++){
        if(itemsList1.get(i).getProdnum()==disablelist.get(j).getProdnum()){
            itemsList1.get(i).setSelection(true);
            break;
        }
    }
}      
CustomAdapter adapter1 = new CustomAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, itemsList1);
listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

And modify getView() of CustomAdapter similar to your ItemBumpingAdapter:

```
if(newListItems.isSelected()){
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(...);
else{
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(...);
}
retrun convertView;
```

Comment: tnq so much for ur time to time response i implimented code by getting position i edited ques se it

Comment: there am getting checked positions now the issue is how to change background color to that array list

Comment: am getting that main list position                                                                                                itemsList1.get(i).setSelection(true);                                                       now how to change that background color

Comment: i tried ur last edited one but showing error in selected

Comment: As I see you have setSelection(true) which should be a method inside ItemsBean, so I think you have the method isSelected() also in ItemsBean. If not, then you need to create it in ItemsBean class [similar to setChecked() and isChecked() in ItemsBean]. Or you can use setChecked() and isChecked() instead.

Comment: K tnq i will and will u please tell i want if check box is selected once it must be allowed to check again , how can we do that?

Comment: If you want your dialog list can be check and uncheck, I think you have to move the code that save checked items to database into a public method inside the adapter and call that method when dialog dismiss. Please post your whole ItemBumpingAdapter if you need help.

Comment: tnq so much for ur time to time response and guidence . finally i made the item disable wt i clicked on dialog popup list

Comment: feeling so much happy